# Filtering exception report for past 24 hours

Tags: date, time, blueprism, rpa

Currently working with Blue Prism and I want my exception report to only bring back exceptions from the last 24 hours.

I have tried using 'Today()' in the 'Report From Dt' and 'Report To Dt' which works fine however there is a chance my process will ru into the next day and thus makes this not viable.

Is there a calculation for the past 24 hours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action "Get Reports Data" from BO "Work Queues" requires an input in form of DateTime variable.

The Today() function outputs a variable of the type Date, which is then cast into the datetime variable. When BluePrism casts a date to datetime, then it sets a time to a midnight. The answer for your problem is that you need to supply the action "Get Reports Data" with the DateTime variable that will be a datetime of now - 24hours!

Example solution to that could be:

```
Now()-MakeTimeSpan(0, 24, 0, 0)
```